# javascript fails in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript

I'm running an old version of slideshowpro. There is a javascript file that configures a div and then loads a swf file. It is running fine on Mac Safari and Mac FF and Win IE. It fails to run on Mac Chrome, Win FF and Win Chrome. There are no error messages, there is just a blank space where the slideshow should load. This is the js file that initiates everything ([js source](http://c2-it.com/docs/ssp.txt)

Then the rest of the code is as follows:

```html
<div id="gallery-1">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 SlideShowPro({
  attributes: {
   id: "gallery-1",
   width: 550,
   height: 400
  },
  mobile: {
   auto: false
  },
  params: {
   bgcolor: "#000000",
   allowfullscreen: true
  },
  flashvars: {
   xmlFilePath: "http://www.studiogomez.com/ssp_director/images.php?gallery=1",
   startup: "Open Gallery"
  }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: This is likely because Flash is blocked on most modern browsers, and Adobe annouced that Flash will officially be retired soon. It would be better to switch to an HTML slideshow.

Comment: Thanks raphael75. We are planning to completely redo the slideshow as it is several years old. We just wanted visitors to still be able to view it until we've made the change. Is there any easy way for visitors to enable flash in Chrome? I don't use it at all.

Comment: I think this is what you need: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-chrome.html